# CF Service continuously restarts every 25 seconds

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

After my laptop froze yesterday I rebooted, and now the ColdFusion 9 Application Server service starts and restarts endlessly!  Although it's set to start automatically, upon bootup it does not start.  So I start it manually.  Then I look at the Windows Event Viewer which reports:

> The ColdFusion 9 Application Server service for the "coldfusion" server was started.  PID is 5788.

That's good.  But then, about 9 seconds later, Event Viewer reports:

> The ColdFusion 9 Application Server service for the "coldfusion" server is restarting.

16 seconds later, the Event Viewer reports that the service has, in fact, started again.  And 9 seconds after that, it reports that the service is starting again.

Unless I manually stop the service, this cycle continues, with the CF service restarting itself every 25 seconds, give or take a second.  Needless to say, I can't use ColdFusion.  When I try to reach a page, I get error 500: `There is no web application configured to service your request`

I am running the developer edition of CF9, Windows. Computer behaves normally otherwise.

---

[Edit]

The coldfusion-out.log includes this:

```
Server coldfusion ready (startup time: 9 seconds)

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR (0xc0000006) at pc=0x6d6e2424, pid=5456, tid=7724

JRE version: 6.0_17-b04
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (14.3-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
Problematic frame:
C  [nio.dll+0x2424]

An error report file with more information is saved as:
C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\bin\hs_err_pid5456.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

The detailed error report, C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\bin\hs_err_pid5456.log, has a ton of information, but I don’t understand much of it.  I’ll be happy to post it all if you think you might be able to make heads or tails of it.

In the event that the only solution is to reinstall CF, can you tell me where to find the config files?  I know I will need jrun-web.xml (and I know where it is), but where, for example, are the datasource definitions found?  I can’t seem to find any folder or file with the settings from the CF Admin.  (The CF Admin won’t run, so I can’t view them that way.)

Comment: Sounds like it's failing to start and trying again; check the CF server logs for why?

Comment: Also, since this is a dev machine, the simplest solution might be to backup the CF config files, uninstall, then reinstall.

Comment: @PeterBoughton: I included the CF log info above. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with Peter. With this sort of thing... I think there's little to be gained from working out "why", whereas you could be up and running again in 20min if you de/reinstall.

Comment: @AdamCameron: Amazingly, nothing changed after uninstalling CF9 and reinstalling CF9. After several attempts to start the CF service manually, it started. Then, like before the uninstall/reinstall, the service keeps restarting itself every 25 seconds. What?! Getting sort of desperate. Any more ideas? My laptop seems to be behaving normally otherwise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should mention I am using the built-in web server.

Comment: Did you export / reimport all the settings, or is this - as far as you can tell - a vanilla install?